# How to bind css class in vue js template within a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js

How do I name my td class the name of the step in this example?

```
<td v-for="steps in item.steps" v:bind:class="item.steps.name">
 {{ item.steps.name }}
</td>
```

In this example, my class gets literally named items.steps.name rather than the return value.  Everything else works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-bind:class` not `v:bind:class`

Comment: That's why i always use ":attribute" to bind ^^
I didn't even see that, nice done pal :)

Comment: can i use v-bind:class and v-bind:style in the same line?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: alright thanks - for some reason i can't bind style?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402920/how-do-i-bind-a-style-to-my-v-for-loop-in-this-example

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are looping over **item.steps** with each iteration named **steps** and you use the variable you are looping over in the class-binding.

Try **steps.name** instead.