# How do I bind a style to my v-for loop in this example?

Tags: vue.js

What am I doing wrong here?  There is no error - but there is also no style being applied when I look via dev tools.

```
<!-- Template -->
<td v-for="steps in item.steps" v-bind:style="steps.name">
 {{ steps.name }}
</td>

// Component definition
computed: {
  endstage() {
    return {
      'background-color': '#f9f9f9',
    };
  }
}
```

steps.name prints and if I bind class to steps.name that works - so not sure what I'm doing wrong with trying to bind style.

update:

In my template, I also am using this example which works fine:

```
<!-- Template -->
<table :style="tableStyle">

// Component definition
computed: {
  tableStyle() {
    return {
      'background-color': '#f9f9f9',
      'border-color': '#C0C0C0',
      'padding': '8px',
      'color': 'red',
      'width': '100%',
      'display': 'table',
      'border': '1px solid #ddd',
    };
  }
}
```

So why can I not do the same for `td` using `steps.name` which in this example results in 'endstage'?

Comment: What does `steps.name` contain? If it's a class name that works when binding to `class`, why are you binding it to `style`? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: steps.name is a string named 'endstage'

Comment: What connects `steps.name` to the `endstage` computed attribute? And what converts that object to a string?

Comment: i am trying to have custom styling for each <td> based on the steps.name

Comment: perhaps a better question is in the OP - if you replace v-bind:style with v-bind:class, the td class becomes endstage.  Why is it that I can bind this to the class but not style?

Answer (score 2):

The output of your template will be something like this:

```html
<td style="endstage">
  endstage
</td>
```

I'm assuming that isn't what you want as `endstage` is not a valid value for the `style` attribute. Note that the computed property isn't being used at all here. It is just trying to set the style to the string `'endstage'`.

I guess what you're trying to do is this?

```html
<td v-for="steps in item.steps" :style="this[steps.name]">
```

Assuming `steps.name` is `'endstage'`, this will use the object returned by the computed property `endstage` as the style. `this[steps.name]` evaluates as `this['endstage']`, which is just `this.endstage`.

It's not a great strategy though as it assumes that all names will have their own computed properties.

If `endstage` is the only name you care about then you could do something like this:

```html
<td v-for="steps in item.steps" :style="steps.name === 'endstage' ? endstage : null">
```

If there are others then it'd be better to use a method:

```html
<td v-for="steps in item.steps" :style="getStyle(steps.name)">
```

with:

```js
methods: {
  getStyle (name) {
    switch (name) {
      case 'endstage':
        return {'background-color': '#f9f9f9'}
      // Other cases here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought style= just refers to my computed method ?  I must not be understanding the basics here, see my updated OP.

Comment: i thought style name can be whatever i want it to be

Comment: All I want to do is custom style my td based on step name

Comment: @david `steps.name` evaluates to the string `'endstage'`. Writing `:style="steps.name"` just sets the `style` attribute to the string `'endstage'`. I repeat, the STRING `'endstage'`. There is nothing in that code to link this string to the computed property with that name. The binding expression is only evaluated once, it won't be evaluated recursively just because it evaluates to a string. In my example I wrote it as `:style="this[steps.name]"`, which will access the computed property `endstage`. It's the dynamic version of `:style="endstage"`.

Comment: Ohhhhh okay I get it now - thanks for the explanation there.

Answer (score 1):

It must be `v-bind` not `v:bind`.

Comment: sorry that was actually a typo from copy/paste, still the issue exists